# Where can I find chess tournaments near me for kids or teens?

Tags: tournament, children

Where can I find chess tournaments near me for kids or teens? I am 13 and in the U.S.

Answer (score 8):

Junior tournaments in the US doesn't narrow it down very much. As a chess player living in the US your first stop should always be the [US Chess Federation website](https://new.uschess.org/about).

If you are looking for tournaments then the USCF has a webpage which allows you to search for "[Upcoming Tournaments](https://new.uschess.org/upcoming-tournaments)". You can apply filters for the dates, type of events (Junior Grand Prix is the closest to "Junior") and proximity.

However this will not list minor internal club competitions which might not be rated. You would do well to also contact your nearest chess club to find out what they have to offer. Again, the USCF can help you. They have a web page where you can [search for chess clubs](https://new.uschess.org/club-search-and-affiliate-directory) in your area.

Answer (score 5):

I've never played chess in the US but if I were you I'd call some of the chess clubs nearby and ask for information. While you can definitely find some events online, the people who are dedicated to this stuff will give you better advice themselves.

Anyway don't hesitate to show up to an adults tournament. Even if that's not what you're looking for, you may end up knowing someone who can help you (a coach, an organizer or even a bunch of fellow kids/teens)